# "This app has no instances deployed" message on deployment

Tags: google-app-engine

I have encountered a Google App Engine problem for which I can not find an answer despite a lot of searching.

I can make a minor tweak to my code - say changing a constant or something, nothing that breaks the app code - and do a deployment using appcfg.py update.

After deployment, nothing works, and I find a "This app has no instances deployed" message in the developer console. Not a single instance is running. Eventually after about ten minutes I start to see instances appearing, the app working fine.

I have maximum idle instances set to 5, I've enabled warmup, and I am well within both quota and budget. My log files don't tell me anything of use.

So this one's got me stumped. I'm not anxious to see a ten minute outage every time I update my code. What is happening here, and how can I ensure that my instances start up as they should when I deploy new code?

Comment: try deploying a different version. The old will continue to run until you flip over to the new.

Comment: Could you write your solution if you solved?

Comment: Sadly not, in that I never menaged to get to the bottom of it. The problem went away of its own accord. I can only suppose it to have been a transitory function of App Engine.